# Unix Error on Mac

Tags: iphone, macos

I've been trying to upload my app to an Iphone, but I get the error:

"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Security::UnixError'
what(): UNIX error exception
Command usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 6"

Any idea of what in the world... ?

Answer (score 2):

That means you haven't set up your developer certificate properly in Xcode. Refer to the instructions in the iPhone developer center.